# How to migrate emails from one outlook.com address to another outlook.com address?

Tags: outlook.com, migration

We have to migrate emails from `user@oldDomain.com` => `user@newDomain.com`. Both oldDomain and newDomain are actually hosted via outlook.com (Live Domains) so it's essentially on the outlook.com infrastructure.

How can I migrate older emails for each user from the older account into the newer account?

Setting up POP3 access throws a popup saying:

> looks like you're trying to download from another Outlook account, try linking ...

[image: Outlook message screenshot]

But we don't want to link, we want all emails from old => new account.

How can we do this?

Comment: just try linking...i've linked 3 accounts and its all very smooth...switching accounts is *extremely easy*

Comment: @AyushShanker: Well, we want to obliterate the old domain. Plus MS no longer supports account switching on outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to achieving such a result is by following these steps:

1. Go to https://account.live.com and sign in using the account `user@oldDomain.com`.
2. On the left menu, click on `Overview > Account aliases`. Once there, and assuming you see both `user@oldDomain.com` and `user@newDomain.com`, you can do make `user@newDomain.com` the primary alias and even delete `user@oldDomain.com` if necessary.

Based on which steps you take, your emails will be accessible primarily through `user@newDomain.com`.

[image]